# Jquery hold cache on page load

Tags: jquery, caching

I want browser to hold cache when page loads, as if now it is loosing cache when the page reloads.

Suppose i first maintained the cache and now when i reload the page and  found that cache looses values and again setting new cache value in browser which is not a good technique to use cache.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Normally you can only give the browser a hint, with the `Expires` header, but it is fully up to the browser, not up to you, what it will cache and what it will not... Are you sure you don't mean cookies or something like that?

Comment: No i am saving data on browser cache and fetching the data directly from cache .But now problem is when i refresh the page all the saved caches disappears.

Comment: you should use the [HTML5 local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) functionalities to do what you want to achieve. It is not a matter of cache. Or you have to use cookies/sessions.

Comment: Solution other than HTML5 Local Storage ?

Comment: Sessions and cookies! Store the values in a cookie and retrieve it on page reload. The cookie is stored on the local computer and will do what you want. Just for my info: why local storage is not an option?

Comment: i have done my working using local storage.
Thanks